# Регулярка с числами. Удалить пробелы и после тире

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка, которая содержит числа, **—** , пробелы между ними, и **см**:
`$string = 50 — 55 см`

Числа могут быть разными.

Как удалить всё и оставить только последнее число: **55**. Без букв, без пробелов и тире?

Пробовал использование `preg_replace('/см/','',$string);` но так я удалю только `см`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '50 — 55 см';
echo preg_replace('/^.*?\b(\d+)\hсм$/m', '$1', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
preg_match_all('/\d+/', '50 — 55 см', $matches);
echo end($matches[0]);
```

Регулярное выражение: `/\d+/` будет выбирать все подстроки, в которых встречается одна или более (квантификатор `+`), цифра (`\d`), а все остальные символы будут проигнорированы.

Все совпадения помещаются в массив `$matches[0]`. Функция `end()` вернёт последний элемент массива - число 55.

Comment: необходимый элемент можно получить без помощи дополнительных функций, если шаблон корректно написать: [`~(\d+)\hсм$\K~`](https://regex101.com/r/uxaIZD/1)

Answer (score 1):

Сделал корявенько, мб есть варианты лучше:

```
if(preg_match('/см/i',$string)){
    $newvalue = strpos($string,"—"); //находим позицию символа
    $string = trim(substr($string,0,$newvalue)); //делим по треб. символу и удаляем возможные пробелы
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$string = '50 — 55 см';
$num = preg_replace('/.*\D+(\d+)\D+$/i', '$1', $string);
```